# Error in dividing one column by another column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns like follows:

```
Sales    Population     Income    Price
14       48777.0        285.0     nan
17       12550.0        1.0       nan     
24       15664.0        14.0      14
9        23796.0        24.0      0 
20       40149.0        63.0      nan
75       39489.0        32.0      nan
```

I need to convert everything to per capita terms, that is for each element in sales, I need to divide it by the corresponding population. For example, for sales, I want to divide it by population to get per capita sales:

```
Per capita sales 
14/48777
17/12550
...
```

The command I use is:

```
data['Per Capita Sales'] = data['Sales'] / data['Population']
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have searched online how to divide one column by another column element-wise, but did not find a safe way to do it... Since the columns with values "nan" and "0" are in the numerator, I don't know why there could be an error...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(data['Sales'])/pd.to_numeric(data['Population'])`

Comment: I imagine the above fixes it, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: This works perfectly after adding errors = 'coerce'. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, at least one of the columns involved is of *string* type.
Instead of converting them only for the division, I propose to convert them
to numbers in advance, for all other operations:

```
data.Sales = pd.to_numeric(data.Sales)
data.Population = pd.to_numeric(data.Population)
```

As I see, all rows contain valid data, so the above (shortened) form should be enough.

But if your data were "dirty" (some entries not convertible to number),
you should add `errors='coerce'` parameter.

Then your original command to divide should work.

If you are not sure about types of columns in your DataFrame, execute:

```
data.info()
```

Or maybe you load your DataFrame from a file, e.g. calling `read_csv`?
In this case include `dtype` parameter (a dictionary in the form *{"column name" : type}*)
to force the required types of particular columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Yes, I used read_csv to import data, and I agree that specifying dtype in read_csv would be the best option, since I have many columns. In the dtype dictionary, I use {"sales" : float}, but got an error saying `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. I think this is why you suggest using `errors='coerce'`, but would this just leave whatever not convertible as N/A?

Comment: If you use *errors='coerce'*, then: 1. Values which could be converted are *floats*. 2. Values not convertible are changed to *NaN* (actually this is a "special case" of *float*). Then take a look at corresponding rows in source file. I think, you will find what is wrong and will be able to correct the wrong values. Sometimes instead of dots there are used commas. In such a case a custom converter is required (instead of *dtype*). Read about *converters* parameter and search the Web for examples.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense and I will see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
df['Per Capita Sales'] = df.astype('float').apply(lambda x: x['Sales']/x['Population'], axis =1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I use the pd.to_numeric and it works well!